# Balance is not updated when user changes account

Tags: reactjs, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to update the address and balance every time the account is changed in *metamask*, however only the account is changing and the balance doesn't get updated.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    let accs = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accs[0]);
    let balanceth = await web3.utils.fromWei(balance,'ether');
    console.log(balanceth+" ether");
    this.setState({ balanceth });
    this.setState({ account:accs[0] });
      window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged',  (accounts) => {

          console.log(accounts[0]);
          this.setState({ account:accounts[0] });
          let acc = this.state.account;
          // Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]!
          web3.eth.getBalance(acc,(err,bal)=> {balance = bal})
          console.log(balance)
          web3.utils.fromWei(balance,'ether',(err,bal)=>{balanceth = bal});
          console.log(acc,balanceth);
          this.setState({ balanceth:balanceth });
  })
  }
```

Comment: can you show your html of input field?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in trying to change the balance inside of a function. So you're not really changing the value of  balance you already defined. try:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(acc,(err,bal)=> {
    this.setState({ balance: bal })
})
```